# Amazon Connect error using Lex as customer input

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am trying to create a demo call centre using AWS connect.

Part of my contact flow makes use of the "Get Customer Input", as I want to use an Amazon lex bot. I have created to divert to a specific working queue. For example, if the user says "sales" they should be directed to the sales queue.

I have tested the Lex bot within the Lex console and it works as intended.

However when testing the Lex integration within AWS connect it will always follow the "error" path on the block after a user says something on the phone.

Here is the CloudWatch log showing the Error result of the module.

```
{
   "Results": "Error",
   "ContactFlowName": "Inbound Flow",
   "ContactFlowModuleType": "GetUserInput",
   "Timestamp": "2022-02-12T18:06:10.940Z"
}
```

Here is the contact flow:
[image]

Here is the settings for the "Get Customer Input Block":
[image]

Here is a test of the Lex bot in the Lex dashboard:
[image: Lex bot test]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was if you're using LexV2 make sure you set the proper Language Attribute as well. Easiest way is using the set Voice block in your Contact Flow, on the very bottom of the block you can enable "set language attribute".

Comment: Especially last part is important:  enable "set language attribute". Without this, the error is stil happening even though the language is set correctly. Thanks a lot James for your helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue in Amazon Connect with Lex as well and resolved it by ensuring that English(US) is added alongside English(GB) in Amazon Lex. Originally the Lex version only had English(GB), but it didn't work and had the same error as above. Only when I added English(US) did it work in Amazon Connect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).